# PHP Curl : mobile User Agent does not support https

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to request page on remote server using PHP-CURL which returns data on https only.
The user agent must be mobile browser.
I've set below user agent rite now :

```
Mozilla/4.1(compatible;Symbian OS;MSIE 5.0;Nokia 3650;424)Opera 6.10 [en]
```

When i request page using above user agent, it says my browser does not support https. If anyone knows which user agent i shall set in my curl request then please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try Android Browser user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1-update1; ru-ru; GT-I9000 Build/ECLAIR) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17
```

Or Opera Mini

```
Opera/9.60 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.2.14912/812; U; ru) Presto/2.4.15
```

Comment: Interesting. Hm... Can you provide me the code snippet? I'll test it. Really, I've never had the same situation. I usually use Androind user agents if I want to check mobile sites and their environment.